# Can I access USB HID device via a Chrome App?

Tags: javascript, usb, google-chrome-app, hid

I have a simple little dongle I want to debug by sending/receiving basic USB messages.  It enumerates as an HID device (like an additional mouse), but am worried that I won't have access to it.  I forgot the hardware and can't test with it for a couple days.

Is it a futile effort to continue building a chrome extension to test it?

Chrome App, USB documentation:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb
Getting-started example:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/usb/knob

Comment: Would you mind moving the accepted mark off my answer? The other answer is now more correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Chrome now proposes a USB HID API. Have a look at the API: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/hid

The API is still defined as experimental at the time of this message. But it is functional.
I have just written a tutorial to explain how to use this API.

Have a look: http://www.appnearme.com/blog/2014/7/21/chrome-usb-hid-controlling-your-usb-device-javascr/

Comment: The API is now stable (except for events, that are coming around in next version)

Answer (score 2):

You can't build a Chrome **Extension** to use that API, only Apps are allowed access.

That said, the JS side of things will probably not be the hard part, the example you linked provides an ample starting point. But I can't quickly find a ready library to do so, so prepare for relatively low-level hardware stuff.

Edit: Seems like there will be an API for that: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=290428

Comment: thanks for the clarification on chrome app vs extension, updated question

Comment: so no access via chrome.usb module?

Comment: @tarabyte There is no high-level API specifically for HID devices, if that's what you're asking.