# chrome.usb.findDevices not working shows error message Failed to open device: Entity not found in chrome://device-log/

Tags: usb, google-chrome-app, hid

Reposting from https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/chromium-apps/noGfn29Aed8/discussion for public reply.

I'm trying to develop a chrome app to communicate with an HID using the chrome.usb API. I am using these functions.

1. chrome.usb.findDevices
2. chrome.usb.controlTransfer

What I've tried so far does not work. The info in `chrome://device-log/` shows this error message.

```
USB     Event   [13:54:01] Failed to open device: Entity not found
```

I am using right VendorId and ProductId in decimal format, Which I have extracted from device manager info.

Here is the code snippet I am using.

```
chrome.usb.findDevices(DEVICE_INFO, function (devices) {
    if (!devices || !devices.length) {
        console.log('device not found');
    }

    console.log("Devices: " + devices);
    console.log(devices[0]);

    var TransferData = {
       "requestType": "class",
       "recipient": "interface",
       "direction": "out",
       "request": 0xx9,
       "value": 0xxx0,
       "index": 0,
       "data": new Uint8Array([00,05, 47, 76, 66, 48, 47,00]).buffer
    };


    setTimeout(function () {
        chrome.usb.controlTransfer(devices[0], TransferData, function (config) {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
            } else {
                console.log('Data Transfer completed');
            }
        });
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues in your question.

1. Check your vendor/product ids. You said you had decimal ids but the `DEVICE_INFO` definition is missing. I see in the snippet of code that you're using `0xx9` in the request field of `TransferData` which is not a valid hex literal. Are you doing the same thing in the `DEVICE_INFO`? If the vid is 1234 decimal, make sure you're not saying 0x1234.
2. There are separate `chrome.` APIs for USB and HID. I'm pretty sure the USB interface will not allow you to manipulate devices that advertise as HID. You must instead use the [`chrome.hid`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/hid) interface for these devices.

There are a few questions here that could have some helpful info for you:

- [Can I access USB HID device via a Chrome App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037402/can-i-access-usb-hid-device-via-a-chrome-app)
- [HID compliant device will not enumerate using chrome.hid API on ChromeOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557114/hid-compliant-device-will-not-enumerate-using-chrome-hid-api-on-chromeos)